# How to avoid hotels with bellhops in the USA

Tags: usa, hotels, tipping

Many guides to tipping in the USA include a specification to tip a "bellhop" at a hotel, which is apparently an employee who expects to be paid separately for the "service" of accompanying the guest from the reception to their room.

The times I have been to America, there has been no such person -- the hotels I stayed at just followed the straightforward standard procedure of *"here's your keycard; your room is number XYZ on the Xth floor, and the elevators are over there -- enjoy your stay"*. But it's possible that I've simply been lucky with the hotels I selected.

When booking a hotel stay online in the USA, is there something in particular one should look for to be sure it's not a place where one will be hit with hidden costs for "bellhop" services?

(Or is it perhaps all a myth intended to scare travelers? When I arrive at a hotel I'll generally have been able to lug my baggage through airports and across a city all by myself, and it seems somewhat incongruous that a hotel would expect me to relinquish control of it for the last few meters between the reception and my room, and pay for the indignity to boot!)

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Heads-Beds-Reckless-So-Called-Hospitality/dp/030794834X is a good read on this particular subject

Comment: The kind of people who stay at high-end hotels usually get a taxi all the way from the airport and never haul them around. Only budget travelers bother with public transport and carry their bags in the city.

Comment: Bellhops and porters were more common before wheeled suitcases became common; thus, it was offered as a service so that guests didn't have to carry their suitcases up to their rooms. With wheels, it takes much less effort to get your suitcases to your rooms, so the service only remains common at higher-end hotels

Comment: i love this answer. i too feel awkward when travelling to places that love to break the personal space bubble.

Comment: Just politely decline their services. No need to tip them if they don't do anything.

Comment: [Just wait until you become a Gold member](https://www.clubcarlson.com/fgp/memberbenefits/home.do)

Comment: Pick a place that calls itself a "hostel" or book via AirBNB.  Or put everything in a backpack and wear it.

Comment: What @calchas said. You can always decline. I do it frequently.

Comment: If you *really* want to avoid bellhops, you could just go online and look up the hotel you're staying at ahead of time - they should list their services offered there, including things like Bellhops.

Comment: As an aside, bellhops are useful for far more than just carrying bags. They are the goto-person for questions like nearby restaurants and theatres, good places to walk, places to avoid, local ordanances and laws, help with local traditions and customs.

Comment: @GreenstoneWalker: Why is that not reception? It would seem natural for such questions to arise some time _after_ arrival.

Comment: @GreenstoneWalker that's concierge service.  You don't even have to use a bellhop for that, but you can.  Pay a bellhop well enough and he'll rearrange all the furniture in your room. You're not being charged by the hotel for this.  You're paying for an optional service.and only as much as you think is right. It's totally your call.  Try over tipping some time.  Especially if you're staying more than one night.  Watch them fall over themselves trying to find something to help you with.  It's fun. They will remember you.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

**You don't need to worry about this. Bellhops are always optional.**

Usually when you check in at a place with bellhops, (and they really only exist in higher end hotels), a bellhop will approach you and say "Can I carry your bags?". You just say "No thanks, we'll be fine."

Sometimes the bellhop will carry the bags anyway, or the receptionist will sumon the bellhop without asking.. Even then you can decline the service. Just say "We'll carry our bags ourselves, thanks". Whatever happens, f they carry your bags without you asking **you are completely entitled to not tip.** You didn't ask for the service, and you have no obligation to pay for it.

Actually you are always entitled to not tip. Tips are always optional, and if you don't want to tip, for any reason, that's entirely up to you. The situation where a bellhop stands around holding out his hand and looking at you pointedly happens only in movies.

As a final note, bellhops are almost certainly paid less than minimum wage, and may not be paid at all.

Comment: I think if someone came up and took my bags while I'm checking in, my response would not be a polite "I'll carry my bags myself, thanks", but "HEY, THAT'S MINE! STOP! THIEF!"

Comment: @HenningMakholm https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=70TfU9R09Qg#t=1m00s

Comment: My dad still travels by himself but can't lift his luggage. (He overpacks, always has.) A bellhop seems better than a full-time paid companion.

Comment: "Bellhops are always optional" -- although some hotels will nominate a person to show you to your room, instead of giving directions. That person will then offer you carry your bag, and it's not necessarily clear, in the event you carry your own bag, how strong is the cultural expectation that this person should be tipped anyway for the service of showing you through the hotel. That person's job title might not be "bellhop", so I'm not sure whether your comments cover this scenario, beyond your observation that even where it's strongly expected to tip, you're entitled not to.

Comment: "Actually you are always entitled to not tip." This is true in the vast majority of circumstances, but not _always_. One common exception is that many restaurants in the U.S. charge a tip automatically for parties above a certain size. Also, when you've received good service (e.g. from a waiter,) while you may be legally entitled to not tip, it's considered extremely rude in places where tips are expected.

Comment: @reirab: one might argue semantics, that *by definition* if it's charged automatically then it's not a tip, it's a service charge. And sure, you're "entitled" not to tip in the same sense that you're "entitled" to tell the waiter to get a better job and stop bothering people for handouts ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop what they do is that they basically fill it for you (typically if you are paying by card). You are always free to reject it so it is still not mandatory, but it requires more effort and even more social awkwardness.

Comment: "The situation where a bellhop stands around holding out his hand and looking at you pointedly happens only in movies." Actually I've had essentially this experience in Germany, at a simple family-run hotel. Not a bellhop, but the receptionist after I asked him to book me a taxi for the next morning.

Comment: @reirab if the tip is included in the bill it's not really tipping to me. But one could make an argument for it being a surcharge that isn't included on the menu, or only as a footnote.

Comment: @CaptainMan You can use whatever term you want for it, but it's intended as a mandatory tip and is generally treated the same way as a voluntary one in all regards except that it's already placed on your bill. This is why you're normally not expected to add an additional tip to it (though, of course, you're generally welcome to add to it to reward good service, if you want.)

Comment: It would be worth noting in your answer that sometimes bellhop service is included automatically (especially at fancier hotels, albeit rare in the U.S.). I found more often then not this service was labeled "free" and sometimes going as far as to say tips would be refused. I was going to comment on the wording of "not entitled to tip", but it seems there is already a thorough discussion on that aspect.

Comment: "The situation where a bellhop stands around holding out his hand and looking at you pointedly happens only in movies." -- false. I once encountered a bellhop who, even after I declined service, held out his hand, cleared his throat, and stared at me. To which I responded by raising an eyebrow, and when he cleared his throat again, I pulled out my wallet and firmly slapped $1 in his hand. (To clarify, I declined his service and asked for a luggage cart which I then proceeded to load without any assistance from him, and that's when he expected to be tipped)

Comment: I've worked at a Bed & Breakfast as an Innkeeper (and cleaner, waiter, dish washer, kitchen help, etc. etc.), and I would always carry our guests bags up the stairs while conversing with them, trying to get to know them so that I can make suggestions, when needed, for their stay. This was part of my job, and I never expected a tip. I was thankful for any tips I've received, but I was just doing my job (which the owner of the B&B was paying us for already).

Comment: In my experience, the only time I have experienced an aggressive demand for a tip from a bellhop was in a relatively cheap hotel in Chicago (one of the few occasions I have stayed in an American hotel at my own expense). I always assumed this is because luxury hotels pay their staff properly.

Answer (score 64):

I've only seen them in higher-end hotels.

I don't understand why it will/should scare people away. It is good customer service, and some people like that.

IMO, bellhops and porters are really useful when you have a lot of bags, or heavy bags (more than one per person), or if you are elderly or handicapped.

They will get them out of your car or taxi, and watch them while you pay the taxi or go park your car.

If there is a porter and you do not want his service, just say something like: "Thanks, I will take care of my bags".

If you want their service, just tip 1 or 2 dollars per bag; more if they are extra heavy or need extra care.

Comment: I find the idea that I will have to give up my bags to a hotel employee rather than continuing to carry them myself like I've done all the way TO the hotel, and being asked to PAY for loss of physical control of my baggage, to be something scary that I'd prefer to avoid.

Comment: @HenningMakholm you don't *have* to do anything with your bags.  Just say "no thank you" as Max suggests.

Comment: The US seems to have this weird idea that it's ok to offer people a "free" service, supposedly at the generosity of the provider. But then not pay the staff, and expect the recipients of the service (who might have happily done without it) to pay up. It's pretty weird to me, and I can understand why people not from that culture might want to avoid it.

Comment: @CMaster AFAIK, the staff ARE paid, but the amount is minimal (and some professions reliant on tips, such as restaurant wait staff, and paid *less* than the standard minimum wage based on the assumption that the majority of their income will be on tips).  It is weird, though, and some businesses are starting to make the transition away from that model (at least for restaurants), although it is still a standard throughout most of the country.

Comment: @HenningMakholm As far as giving up physical control of your baggage, the bellhops/porters will frequently escort you to the room, so the bags never leave your sight (although some higher end hotels will have the bags come up later, presumably to make it seem "classier").  Even in high-end hotels, though, a simple "no thanks" is sufficient to avoid the service.

Comment: @Beofett; or have the bags come in faster and set up on the bag stands; and suit bag properly hanged;

Comment: I think this might be down to cultural differences. I (like many other Europeans I know) value my privacy and consider mandatory interaction with strangers over which I have little control to be an assault on that privacy.This problem is exacerbated by the social awkwardness of being expected to determine the value of the stranger's help when, in fact, you would be more comfortable if they didn't help at all.

Comment: @Ubiquitous People keep talking about "mandatory" interactions, but it has been said repeatedly that this is entirely optional, and not even available at many locations.  Terms like "assault on privacy" and "loss of physical control of my baggage" are hyperbole that do not in any way accurately describe this service.

Comment: @Beofett It depends on how familiar you are with foreign customs. Firstly, does refusing a bellhop's aid violate some American norm? Is it considered rude? It's hard for an outsider to know the answer (much like not tipping is fine in many countries, but seems to be heavily frowned upon in the US; you only know these things if you are familiar with local customs). Secondly, it's not like you are always asked and given time to think about whether you want help or not: some places I have been to operate under the assumption that you do and you might not realise what is happening until too late.

Comment: @beofett in my experience they do seem to be visibly aggrieved (not rude, but body language tells it all) by declining their service. It's an unnecessary and awkward hassle to navigate because somehow minimum wages aren't really a minimum.

Comment: as a southern european i support @Ubiquitous 's message. We don't like completely strange people ( uniformely dressed or not ) step that much into our personal space (which includes relatives, kids, wives / girlfriends, pets and luggage), let's not start on the "getting paid for that intrusion" part.

Comment: @Ubiquitous Those are fair points, as are Flexo's. However, being unfamiliar with the local customs does not equate to them being mandatory.  That's the whole point of sites like this: to explain the intricacies of the local customs.  It is for this reason that I think it is helpful to stop referring to it as mandatory, because people looking for clarification might be confused by all the people complaining about how it is a mandatory service. They'll be better served by explanations as to how to decline, or that it may be assumed they'll want the service, so be prepared to decline quickly.

Comment: @Ubiquitous and CptEric Your comments about a stranger stepping into your personal space are amusing. I have always seen that Americans are more "sensitive" to privacy and personal space than Europeans. In any European cafe, it is perfectly acceptable to just sit down with a random stranger on the same table on the sidewalk and even start a conversation. In America, it doesn't matter if your are heading for a table at a cafe or for a urinal in the bathroom, you maximize the distance between you and all others present with you.

Comment: @CMaster the service isn't really free and no-one in the US expects it to be. This is particularly true for restaurant waiters but it is true for most other professions (it is considered normal to tip bell hops, concierges and even hotel maids). The one result of this approach is that just about every person in these positions in the US actually tries to be helpful, polite and nice to interact with unlike most of Europe where many service personnel seem to be incredibly annoyed that you are bothering them to do their job.

Comment: Reading comments like *"I lost physical control of my baggage when the bellhop carried it, and I had to pay!"* are pretty funny considering that once you leave the room hotel employees could be doing literally anything with your baggage, even trying on all your clothes while you're away, and you *had to pay* to stay at the hotel in the first place. If you don't trust the hotel's employees then definitely **don't sleep there**.

Comment: @FixedPoint, even reading about the possibility of those interactions taking place made me shiver a bit. You _definitely_ do not do those things in large parts of Europe (can't speak for all).

Comment: @FixedPoint it's not only not perfectly acceptable, it will get you a sever warning or a punch on the face on most countries i've visited.

Comment: @CMaster: I live here in the US. I consider this practice by certain corporations to be wrong.

Comment: @Ubiquitous It may be cultural but as a native American I also feel the same way and detest random people intruding on my life to offer services I neither want nor need who act miffed after I am forced to decline their services.

Comment: @FixedPoint *In any European cafe, it is perfectly acceptable to just sit down with a random stranger on the same table on the sidewalk and even start a conversation.* What on Earth are you talking about? Try that in France and you'll get horrified stares, for example. The only time in my life some random stranger came up to me and struck up a conversation unprompted was in the Boston metro. The only times in my life I've been hugged by someone other than family or very close friends were in the USA. It's also rather ridiculous to offer such advice that supposedly applies to *all of Europe*...

Comment: I'm not sure you've been to Europe recently, @FixedPoint, or at least not the major parts of it. Certainly in the UK, in France, Spain, Portugal, Germany, Italy, Switzerland, etc, etc, that used to be the case some significant time ago; if you did that sort of thing today you'd be rather less politely told to remove yourself from your would-be compatriot's presence.

Comment: But really, what's that nonsense about "intrusion of privacy" and all that jazz? *You go to a hotel in order to get their services, intentionally.* A bellhop is such a service. Either you use it or you don't, you simply decline it just as you would decline a waiter suggesting to refill your glass when you don't want it to be refilled. As simple as that. What has this world come to when simple and routine human interactions like these are filtered through pompous absurdities like "intrusion of personal space" or "physical control of luggage"?

Comment: Just my 2c as a German, but the idea that someone would take my luggage without me expressly allowing them to just sounds off to me. Similarly, if I don't expect it and people touch me, thats very uncomfortable.

Answer (score 31):

> ... a "bellhop" ... is apparently an employee who expects to be paid separately for the "service" of accompanying the guest from the reception to their room.

Correct.

> But it's possible that I've simply been lucky with the hotels I selected.

It has little to do with luck. You are most likely not splurging on very expensive hotels.

> When booking a hotel stay online in the USA, is there something in particular one should look for to be sure it's not a place where one will be hit with hidden costs for "bellhop" services?

Don't stay at very upscale hotels. Or, if you want to / are forced to stay at an upscale hotel, just say "I got it man, thanks anyway" once or twice and they'll let you handle your own bags.

> I'll generally have been able to lug my baggage

You're not the target market for bellhop services. The economics of hiring bellhops require a constant stream of well-to-do travelers who expect someone else to carry their bags.

Comment: I disagree. We often stay at mid-range hotels (usually in Las Vegas), and are often greeted by a smiling bellhop with a cart to ferry our bags to our room. (If we only have one or two bags, we'll politely decline.)

Answer (score 25):

### The Bellhop / Bellboy

This position is a relic from a previous era. Originally, an older child or very young adult would fill this entry level position. The Desk clerk would ring a bell to summon them, and they would "hop" to it, hence the name. They were general labor, lugging, carting, and escorting, delivering messages and packages, and erranting on demand. Pay was poor. In some regions, the bellboy would also be a local urchin, and thus would have a wide ranging street knowledge, which the hotel and/or patrons could leverage to find good deals or discounts (usually relatives or friends), special services, and lesser known sites worthy of visiting. This 'extra knowledge' or 'local tips' was often rewarded by grateful patrons with change and spare cash. Frequent customers (or those that tipped well) would find that their reputation would spread and service could be decidedly faster and of higher quality than otherwise.

The Bellhop position clings to existence in certain high-end hotels, while other positions from the same era have fallen by the wayside as culture and economics have changed over time: The elevator operator, the "pit crew" at gas stations, the doorman, the butler, room service (food), shoeshine boys, newsies, and more. Some of these positions can still be found here and there, but are much less common with automation, changing values and culture and economics.

The media has long glamorized the generously tipping high roller, which may have something to do with the wide spread of the tipping phenomena in American culture. Even to this day, certain types of service staff (waiters, mostly) are paid significantly less in anticipation of their receiving tips; an ongoing debate and challenge.

### Today's Views

In modern America, it is not considered impolite to refuse the service, if you can find it, and it is much less likely that they will be highly knowledgeable locals. In fact, it is increasingly rare to run into an establishment that has any. I don't know of any in my immediate area, nor the last four or five places I have lived in. Unless you are in the habit of frequenting really expensive places to stay, or are in a large city where competition drives the service, you are not likely to find one.

On the flip side, if they do happen to be a local with street knowledge, getting on their good side can only benefit you.

### How to guarantee not meeting a bellhop

Call the hotel and ask if they provide that service prior to your booking a room at that hotel.

Comment: Taking your chances will likely result in you not meeting one, unless you stay at expensive or geographically competitive locations. I suggest that one simply calls and asks if the hotel provides such a service, if you want to ensure an absolute avoidance.

Comment: _This position is a relic from a previous era._ Indeed, [wheeled suitcases were invented in 1970](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baggage#Wheels), and even then, they were not an instant success.

Comment: Room service is normal in 4/5 star hotels. Just like carrying luggage to the room for guests.

Comment: Perhaps so. I've never really seen the point of wasting so much money just to sleep and/or stay somewhere, so I don't recall ever staying at one, despite living in and traveling through Europe, Asia, and the Americas. Perhaps that is simply due to being raised in an era of thriftiness and coming from a poor background.

Answer (score 21):

Trivago will let you see if the hotel has bellhop service but it's listed as Porter Service on that site. Find a potential hotel, click it in the listings, and then click Hotel Details. Porter service will be listed if the hotel has reported to Trivago that they offer the service. I don't know the details of how Trivago gets their data, but I suppose it might be possible that a hotel offers porter/bellhop service but just hasn't let Trivago know.

Your preferred hotel booking site might have something similar and if not, you can always use Trivago for a double-check before booking through your preferred site.

There's also the option of calling the hotel.

And was said in the previous answer, you always have the option of saying "No thanks, I'll get these myself" if a bellhop appears.

Answer (score 3):

Basically any hotel that you stay in should have bellhop service in the US (even the lower end ones, so long as it's not a motel), but it is always optional. General tip for this ranges (from what I've seen) from about $2-$10, but a $10-$20 tip can make a huge difference in the quality of your stay (once a hotel brought an actual microwave to my room because I came in with leftovers and the bellhop saw me.) I'm not sure if I would consider it a hidden cost because the service itself is optional. You have to tip servers in restaurants more than that anyway.

Tl;dr - you should never feel obligated to use a bellhop, whether you see them or not, but if you do use one you should tip them.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45651/discussion-on-answer-by-tam-hartman-how-to-avoid-hotels-with-bellhops-in-the-usa).

Answer (score 3):

Almost every hotel in the US will have a "bellhop" service. Normally though you have to ask for it. Generally while the service still exists, there is no longer a person that does it, and if you ask, one of the courtesy staff will come lug your stuff around for you. It's not common that people ask anymore, but if you have a hard time with your luggage then, you can always ask.

The day of my wedding I used the service because I had too many people's luggage to handle my self. Other then that I have never used it.

Now, if you use the service you should tip. Anything from $2 to $20 is normal, and it's more about how good of a job you think they did.  But again the service is always optional, and generally has to be asked for.

Bit of a warning, In the US your expected to tip a lot of people. Basically anyone in service. Make sure you adjust your costs for that. Waiters, delivery boys, laundry service, the concierge, taxis, etc. all expect tips. 15% is the normal tip. I'm not fond of this policy, but it is what it is. Tipping is always optional, but almost always worth it.

For example, I always tip the concierge at the hotels I stay at (I general stay at the same hotels). When my wife and I went to see a concert, the concierge "helped" by ringing the room to let us know the cab was there, calling and arranging for the cab. Talking to the cab driver and making sure he knew where to drop us off. Arranging for the pickup,  making dinner reservations for us. Arranging for the pickup there, and the return trip to the hotel. He then made sure we were last on the list of rooms to be cleaned so we could sleep in a bit, and still get our room cleaned. Tipping was well worth it. He made our little 4 day get away very relaxing and stress free. Even arranged with the rental car company delivery and pickup of the car at the hotel. Sure all of those things could be done by us, but we didn't have to.

Point is this. In the US you are expected to tip a lot. It's not mandatory, but is generally advised. Don't tip for bad service, tips at 10%-15% for acceptable service and 20%-30% for exceptional service. The bellhop service still exists in most US hotels, and if used should be tipped. The position of bellhop is rare, and your usually not going to see one unless you ask for it.